# Multimarkdown well configured header data

Tags: html, xhtml, markdown, multimarkdown

Hi I'm trying to get the top of my multimarkdown file to look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Test of markdown</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css" />
    </head>
```

I know how to add the following metatags:

```
Title: Test of markdown
CSS: ../main.css
Quotes language: english
```

which gives me :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test of markdown</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css"/>
    </head>
```

But I'm not sure how to add the rest. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any native `markdown` way to do this but you could run a little script across the generated HTML if you really feel you need to do this.

This is a simple Python 3 option that might get you started. This could be improved in many ways but wanted to keep it simple. An obvious idea would be to give it a folder and have it process every HTML file in the folder. But I hope this gives the idea.

**Example code:**

```
filepath = input('What is the full file path to the file? - ')

htmldoctype = ' '.join([
    '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"',
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">',
    '\n'
])

htmlinfo = ('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n')

inlines = []

try:
    with open(filepath, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.strip() == '<!DOCTYPE html>':
                inlines.append(htmldoctype)
            elif line.strip() == '<html>':
                inlines.append(htmlinfo)
            else:
                inlines.append(line)
except Exception:
    print('something went wrong in get')

try:
    with open(filepath, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        for line in inlines:
            outfile.write(line)
except Exception:
    print('something went wrong in write')
```

**Input:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test of markdown</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css"/>
      </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test of markdown</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
  test
</body>
</html>
```